# Is there an html API to know which ancestor determines an element's dimensions?

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a div. Deeeeeeeeeeply nested inside a page.

For some reason, this div has a size, which DevTools precisely gives me (*it's 370.158px, for the curious ones.*)

However I have *no* idea which ancestor(s?) has(have?) the "width", "height", "min-width", "position", "display", or "color" property that determines those dimensions.

Is there a programmatical way to find out ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249660/get-element-from-which-css-rule-is-being-inherited

Comment: Chrome's develop tools will show you what you need.

Comment: @j08691 it will if I manually climb up the ancestor tree, which is impractical in my case.