# jquery: custom selector not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-selectors

I am trying to create a custom jquery selector to return the bool of `css("visibility") == "inherit"` but it doesn't seem to be working. Below is the code...

```
$.expr[":"].crazyvisible = function(a) {
    var elem = $(a);
    return (elem.css("visibility") == "inherit");
};
```

This is the code I'm using the selector in (i've also tried live)...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span#Request1_multiconditionvalidator2").delegate(":crazyvisible","attachErrorMessage", function() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to be working", please.

Comment: @Henning Makholm the attachErrorMessage function does not fire.

Comment: @BoltClock how can I check that visibility == inherit OR visibility != hidden

Comment: @bflemi3: You just need to know if it's not hidden? What if it inherited `hidden` from its parent?

Comment: @BoltClock There is another script that I do not have access to that is changing visibility to inherit on that span when a certain condition is met. I'm only trying to see when this span no longer has it's visibility set to hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your selector or your `.delegate()` call as far as I can tell. The problem is that the `.css()` function returns the computed style of an element, so you will never get `'inherit'` as the value because that's then computed to whatever style an element's parent has instead.

You can find more info on checking inherited CSS properties using jQuery in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000108/how-can-i-tell-if-a-particular-css-property-is-inherited-with-jquery) — in short, though, it's not easy to do so.

**EDIT:** if you only need to know if an element isn't `'hidden'`, whether inherited or not, you can just do this:

```
$.expr[":"].crazyvisible = function(a) {
    var elem = $(a);
    return elem.css("visibility") != "hidden";
};
```

Comment: for some reason this isn't working. I put a watch in firebug for $("span#Request1_multiconditionvalidator2").css("visibility") and it equaled hidden. then I met the condition to unhide the span and it equaled inherit

Comment: just an update. I tried this in the firebug watch... $("span#Request1_multiconditionvalidator2:crazyvisible").attr("id") and got "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: visibility"

Comment: I'm going to give you the answer because under normal circumstances this would work perfectly. I think I'm having issues because another script that I don't have access to is causing issues with my code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Here's hoping you get it sorted!