# Invert text-color of a specific element (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

How do I invert the text-color of an element using jQuery?

```
<div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0)">Invert me</div>
```

Comment: In a nutshell, get the colour, turn it into 3 decimal values (it's returned as hex IIRC) and subtract those values from 255. You then have your R, G and B channels and you use `$.css()` to apply them again.

Comment: http://webhole.net/2010/01/06/how-to-invert-an-elements-color/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766201/javascript-invert-color-on-all-elements-of-a-page

Comment: @JamWaffles You should make this an answer. But do you really need the entire jQuery library to do this simple task? Maybe something like: `document.getElementById('').style.color = invert(0, 0, 0); function invert(r, g, b){r = 255-r, g = 255-g, b=255-b; return {'r':r,'g':g,'b':b}}`

Comment: @Relic Excellent point. It can of course be done without jQuery, but the OP is using it, so it's a little better to use jQuery in this case, although the only thing it makes easier is element selection.

Answer (score 11):

A bit late but better late than never:

```
function invert(rgb) {
  rgb = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments).match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)/g);
  for (var i = 0; i < rgb.length; i++) {
    rgb[i] = (i === 3 ? 1 : 255) - rgb[i];
  }
  return rgb;
}

console.log(
  invert('rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)'), // 0, 255, 255, 0.7
  invert('rgb(255, 0, 0)'), // 0, 255, 255
  invert('255, 0, 0'), // 0, 255, 255
  invert(255, 0, 0) // 0, 255, 255
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First load `http://www.phpied.com/files/rgbcolor/rgbcolor.js`

Then you can do

```
$.fn.invertElement = function() {
  var prop = 'color';

  if (!this.css(prop)) return;

  var color = new RGBColor(this.css(prop));
  if (color.ok) {
    this.css(prop, 'rgb(' + (255 - color.r) + ',' + (255 - color.g) + ',' + (255 - color.b) + ')');
  }
};

$('div').invertElement();
```

This should also work when the color property is specified with a word (like "black") rather than an RGB value.  It won't work well with transparency, however.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great 'Hexadecimal Color Inverter' function wrote by Matt LaGrandeur (http://www.mattlag.com/)

```
function invertHex(hexnum){
  if(hexnum.length != 6) {
    console.error("Hex color must be six hex numbers in length.");
    return false;
  }

  hexnum = hexnum.toUpperCase();
  var splitnum = hexnum.split("");
  var resultnum = "";
  var simplenum = "FEDCBA9876".split("");
  var complexnum = new Array();
  complexnum.A = "5";
  complexnum.B = "4";
  complexnum.C = "3";
  complexnum.D = "2";
  complexnum.E = "1";
  complexnum.F = "0";

  for(i=0; i<6; i++){
    if(!isNaN(splitnum[i])) {
      resultnum += simplenum[splitnum[i]]; 
    } else if(complexnum[splitnum[i]]){
      resultnum += complexnum[splitnum[i]]; 
    } else {
      console.error("Hex colors must only include hex numbers 0-9, and A-F");
      return false;
    }
  }

  return resultnum;
}
```

Source is here:
http://www.mattlag.com/scripting/hexcolorinverter.php

Answer (score 1):

For newer browsers (>2016), there is no need to do any extra calculations thanks to the CSS `filter` property. Setting the value to `invert(1)` will invert the foreground color.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#invert

```js
$('#invert-me').css({ filter: 'invert(1)' });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="invert-me" style="color: rgb(0, 255, 0);">Invert me (Opposite of green is magenta)</div>
```