# How can I invert color using CSS?

Tags: css, colors

HTML

```
<div>
    <p>inverted color</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    background-color: #f00;
}
p { 
    color: /* how to use inverted color here in relation with div background ? */
}
```

Is there any way to invert the `p` color with CSS?

There is `color: transparent;` why not `color: invert;` even in CSS3?

Comment: -webkit-filter: invert(100%);

Comment: This could be very helpfull to you: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/say-hello-to-css3-filters/

Comment: In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5UHM/2/) I tried to combine 3 approaches: CSS filter for WebKit, SVG filter for Firefox, and the brilliant trick with `outline-color: invert` [invented by Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/2011/04/invert-a-whole-webpage-with-css-only/) for IE. Unfortunately, Opera (Presto) didn't clip the area filled with outline by `overflow`, so it won't work there. I hope that this demo may still be useful for the further experiments.

Comment: @Ronvander the link is dead

Comment: This is why I find it insane to not just embed the information.  The only real advantage of making the link is in the form of SEO backlink credit, which also would be useless if the link expired.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Add the same color of the background to the paragraph and then invert with CSS:

```css
div {
    background-color: #f00;
}

p { 
    color: #f00;
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>inverted color</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This inverts the `color`, but not the `background`. It just so happens that `color` is set to the same as `background-color`. See [below](/a/58460326/579078) for a solution that inverts the backdrop.

Answer (score 49):

Here is a different approach using `mix-blend-mode: difference`, that will actually invert whatever the background is, not just a single colour:

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
}
p {
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscit elit, sed do</p>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 `mix-blend-mode: difference` works where `filter: invert(100%)` fails when used with `position: fixed` (say modals) https://stackoverflow.com/a/37953806/366332

Comment: Doesn't work on [economist.com](https://www.economist.com/). `html {mix-blend-mode: difference !important;}` does not invert the background. (neither does `html {filter: invert(100%) !important;}`)

Comment: @tejasvi88 `mix-blend-mode` implies two layers will "mix" together. you must `mix-blend-mode` on a child node. in the example, `p` mixes with `div`, the effect is `p` is inverted in relation to the contents of `div` beneath it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to handle this is to use JavaScript

Try this [Invert text color of a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101224/invert-text-color-of-a-specific-element-using-jquery)

If you do this with css3 it's only compatible with the newest browser versions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if you are wanting to invert the whole `p` and not just the colour, then the new way to do it is to use [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

```css
div {
  background-color: #f00;
  padding: 2px;
}

p {
  color: #f00;
  backdrop-filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>inverted color</p>
</div>
```