# Make Div Mask Background Image to Match Parent Background Image

Tags: html, css, background-image, mask

I am trying to accomplish an effect where it looks like the "container" div is inverting the background image of the "parent" div. From my research I can't seem to find a way other than the "parent" and the "container" being the same size with different backgrounds, and the "content" div masking the "container" div. Here is an image of what I would like it to look like.

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The "parent" div has a normal background, while the "container" div (same size as "parent") has an inverted version of the "parent" background (inverted via thrid party program, I am not trying to invert it via css).

My question is, what CSS do I need to apply to the "content" and "container" div to achieve a mask where the "container" div's background is only shown through the "content" div?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invert color using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741629/invert-color-using-css)

Comment: I'm not trying to invert via css. I'm trying to mask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea is to play with [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) and adjust padding to control how much background you will show from the inner container:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800?image=1069) center/cover;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/g/1000/800?image=1069) center/cover;
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding: 100px calc(100% - 300px) 100px 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Some text
  </div>
</div>
```

This can also be done with one container and multiple backgrounds:

```css
.container {
 height:300px;
 background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/g/1000/800?image=1069) center/cover,
    url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800?image=1069) center/cover;
  background-clip:
    content-box,
    padding-box;
  padding:100px calc(100% - 300px) 100px 50px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    Some text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mix-blend-mode` though it will affect any contents of the `.content` div.

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800?image2045) center/cover;
  padding: 50px;
}

.content {
  width: 220px;
  height: 180px;
  background: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```