# What's the onload equivalent for most elements?

Tags: javascript, html

[How to add onload event to a div element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057236/3310334) points out that the `onload` attribute only works for `<body>` and external sources (like `<script>`).

So for the example in that question:

```
<div onload="oQuickReply.swap();" ></div>
```

the onload contents will never be called.

---

How can I trigger some javascript to run when a div is added to the page, via the div element HTML itself?

As we've seen

```
$('<div onload="myFunction()"></div>').appendTo('body');
```

Won't work. `myFunction` will not be called, because `onload` isn't even triggered for divs.

---

I am creating HTML on the backend using C# Razor/DevExtreme, and it doesn't load the entire webpage at once but [I want to run some code after some part of the webpage has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68542423/3310334). This is why i can't just

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body');
myFunction();
```

Comment: `appendTo` is immediate. Is there a reason you can't just do `$('<div></div>').appendTo('body'); myFunction()`?

Comment: @edemaine yeah, I am not the one doing the injecting

Comment: You cannot trigger an event using only the markup inside the inserted element. You'll need to have the trigger in place before inserting. Try document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', myFunction): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778962/handler-for-dynamically-created-dom-nodes-as-they-are-inserted (of course, you'll need to filter for the nodes of interest -- here you _can_ insert some markup into the new DOM node that you then can use as a filter criterion in myFunction).

Comment: @orithena looks like the best workaround, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most elements don't load anything, they just *are*.

To do something after you add a DIV to the DOM, just do that thing on the next line of code:

```
$('<div onload="myFunction()"></div>').appendTo('body');
console.log("The div will be in the DOM now");
```

Comment: I don't have control of this part of the code, only the HTML that will be rendered and some JavaScript

Comment: I'd remove the onload and replace console.log(...) with myFunction(). ^^

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68542423/3310334 in case you want to see the original problem