# Windows Phone browser live html modification

Tags: c#, xaml, browser, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I haven't looked into it very much but am struggling to find relevant information on the topic. I basically want to create a browser that applies a filter to a webpage by changing colors in a webpage. My guess is that I will have to change the html once loaded or something, would this work? Do I have other options?

PS. I don't just want to make every color darker, I would more like to invert the colors.

Edit:
If any you were wondering, I am talking about the XAML browser component that can be used in a Windows Phone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do that is to inject some Javascript into your page once it has loaded.

To do that, you need to set the `IsScriptEnabled` to `true` on your `WebBrowser` control and then subscribe to the `Navigated` event.

When that event occurs you can inject some JS codeby using the `WebBrowser.InvokeScript` method.

Here is an example of JS code that darken the page : [JavaScript: Invert color on all elements of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766201/javascript-invert-color-on-all-elements-of-a-page)

Comment: Thanks, this looks as if it can work. All issue is that the JavaScript you directed me to uses jQuery and this injection story does not seem to support jQuery. Am I wrong and if not, do you have any other JavaScript that I can try?

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't require jQuery. Look at the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nikita_turing/jVKw6/3/

Comment: Thanks but that script does not seem to work for my normal Internet Explorer so I doubt it will work on mobile Internet Explorer. Are you also using IE? If so please confirm if there isn't just something wrong with my IE?

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about in a PC internet browser, you can find an add-on to execute Javascript automatically, such as Greasemonkey for Firefox. If you are talking about Windows Phone's Internet Explorer, I don't really know what you could do there, as I don't think they allow add-ons.

Comment: I am talking about the XAML browser component that can be used in a Windows Phone application.