# How come this color assignment is not affecting all elements on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, code-injection

I'm working off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766201/javascript-invert-color-on-all-elements-of-a-page), except with pure Javascript, and not jquery. I've attempted to change all elements that have a color assignment to a pink color. I'm walking through the elements backwards in my loop. Injecting this code on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page, for example, only changes a few background colors; leaving many untouched, even though inspecting the element has a CSS color property. How come this color assignment is not affecting all elements on the page that have a color property?

```
// CSS properties that can change color
let CSSPropsColor =
[
"background",
"background-color",
"text-shadow",
"text-decoration-color",
"text-emphasis-color",
"caret-color",
"border-color",
"border-left-color",
"border-right-color",
"border-top-color",
"border-bottom-color",
"border-block-start-color",
"border-block-end-color",
"border-inline-start-color",
"border-inline-end-color",
"column-rule-color",
"outline-color",
"color",
]

function pinkAll()
{
    // get all elements
    var allEl = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    
    // walk backwards through loop
    for (var i=allEl.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
            var color = null;
            
            for (var prop in CSSPropsColor) {
                prop = CSSPropsColor[prop];
                
                //if we can't find this property or it's null, continue
                if (!allEl[i].style[prop]) continue;
                
                var bgColor = window.getComputedStyle(allEl[i],null).getPropertyValue(prop).toString();
                
                let firstChar = bgColor.charAt(0);
                
                if(firstChar !== "r" && firstChar !== "#") continue;
                
                allEl[i].style[prop] = "#EC00FF" // change element color to PINK
                
            }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // sometimes 'load' is not enough, and I have to wait a bit
    let timeout = setTimeout(pinkAll, 500);
})
```

Comment: `for/in` loops should be used to iterate objects, not arrays. For arrays, use counting loops or `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement:  `if (!allEl[i].style[prop]) continue;` is continuing anytime it encounters an element wherein the style is not set *inline*. Using `if (!window.getComputedStyle(allEl[i],null).getPropertyValue(prop)) continue;` sets the whole page pink...